# Change apostrophe-search results page size

Tags: apostrophe-cms

There is probably a property to set the search results page size (looks like it defaults to 10). How can I increase the page size?

I found this in the \node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-search\ module:

```
perPage: 10
```

but changing this property in my lib\modules\apostrophe-search\index.js didn't do the trick:

```
module.exports = {  
   perPage: 500
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the results were adjusted as a result of this update after all. Either this module or changing the result in lib\modules\apostrophe-blog-pages\index.js to:

```
module.exports = {  
   perPage: 25
}
```